# Declaração de variáveis local numa função do PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1    
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()
```

resultado-> 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597

Mas se eu declarar as variáveis a e b em linhas diferentes, ele me trás outro resultado:

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=' ')
        a = b      `declarar a = b, não seria o mesmo que acima`
        b = a + b
     print()
```

resultado -> 0 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024

A dúvida é a seguinte, se eu declarar `a, b = b, a+b` não seria o mesmo que eu declarar:

```
a = b
b = b + a
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

A chave pra entender isso é que tudo que está a direita do `=` é executado antes pela linguagem, e depois ela faz as atribuições -

então ao fazer

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

(que é o mesmo que :

```
a, b = (b, a + b)
```

Python dispensa os parenteses se não há ambiguidade)

o que acontece é que é criada um objeto do tipo tupla com o valor atual de b, e o valor de `a + b` como seus dois elementos. Essa tpla fica temporariamente na memória, como resultado da expressão - e em seguida, esses valores são distribuidos e atribuidos respectivamente para a e para b.

Se você faz:

```
a = b
```

em uma linha separada, o valor de `a` já foi sobre-escrito ao fazer `a + b` em outra linha (e a linguagem não seria utilizável se fizesse algo parecido com isso - seria completamente imprevisível).

Vale lembrar que esse idioma de calcular uma tupla e associar seus valores numa mesma linha é usado, por que sem eesse recurso você precisaria de uma terceira variável só pra fazer essa troca -  o código na maioria das outras linguagens, que não tem esse recurso tem que ser:

```
c = a
a = b
b = c + b
```

Se você escrever algo assim:

```
a, b = inspecionar = b, a+b
print(a, b, inspecionar)
```

a linguagem, além de distribuir os valores da tupla teporária para `a` e `b`, vai guardar a tupla inteira na variável `inspecionar`. Esse `print` a mais vai te ajudar a entender o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Veja bem Rafael.
Quando você faz

```
a, b = a, a+b
```

a variavel A e a variavel B recebe o valor ao mesmo tempo, assim quando B recebe a+b 
A ainda está com o valor do loop anterior o valor anterior.

Quando você faz

```
a = b
b = a+b
```

no momento que B recebe o valor a variável A já mudou o valor, por isso a diferença, entendeu?